# git checkout files from other branch under a different name

Tags: git

I'm working with binary files and want to compare two versions of a file from different branches. With text files I could just `show` the file content and redirect it to a new file, but in this case I need a specific directory structure, e.g.:
`./foo/bar/file.bin`. I want to check out the entire `./foo/bar/file.bin` from another branch to, say, `./new/bar/file.bin`, then I would be able to use my specific program to look at the contents of those files (a proprietary closed-source program that expects the data in a certain format).

Is there a semi-easy (or easy :)) way to do this with git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git read-tree -u --prefix=new/bar thatbranch:foo/bar
git reset -- @:new
```

the read-tree loads the index and work tree, the reset yanks the index entries.

`git show thatbranch:some/binaryfile > newbinaryfile` works for one-at-a-time stuff too, contrary to apparent expectation, show doesn't thinks everything's text. It just shows what's in the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
git worktree add ${path_to_new} ${branch}
```

The command checks out the branch into the path `./new`. You could remove `./new` when you think it's not necessary any more.

```
git worktree remove ${path_to_new}
# or
rm -rf ${path_to_new}
git worktree prune
```